# Prototype.js & document.createElement()

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

all
I'm learning prototype.js now. There's something look strange. For example, below is the code fragment I run in firebug, the url is http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/, because there is prototype.js in the page.

```
var el2 = document.createElement('div');
var k=0;
for(var i in el2){ k++};
console.log(k);
```

The result is 262, it is very very strange. Because if I run the same code in a page without prototype.js, the result is 195. My question is how prototype.js affect the document.createElement method. I query document.createElement in prototype.js, I cannot find any code like document.createElement=function(){}.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you posted you are looping through the element object and counting the number of properties on that element object.

As other posters have noted PrototypeJS adds additional methods and properties to the native Javascript definition of the HTMLElement.

Please take a look at the Element namespace http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/ which lists all the methods and properties that PrototypeJS adds.

**EDIT with more information**

How does PrototypeJS add new methods to an element?

Firstly you need to understand how a javascript prototype works - the easiest definition is it is a blueprint for building an object, and when a new object of that type is created that object has all the methods defined in that blueprint as well as any further up the prototype chain.

Easiest example of a prototype chain

```
 DIVElement -> HTMLElement -> Object
```

So a new div element gets all the methods of DIVElement prototype, HTMLElement prototype, and Object prototype.

This is also why it is not advisable to extend the Object prototype because everything copies from that prototype.

So then PrototypeJS extends the `HTMLElement.prototype` object with new methods that do not exist natively in most browsers so that whenever a new HTML element is created in javascript it gets copies of the PrototypeJS methods.

For a specific place in the source code

```
Object.extend(GLOBAL.Element, {
  extend:     extend,
  addMethods: addMethods
});
```

This is at the end of many feature detections to see what elements the browser supports etc.

Comment: Hi, according to the api document, I know prototypejs do native extensions. This is the conclusion which api document tell us. I just want to know how prototypejs do it. As I described, I cannot find any code in protytype.js which replace or modify HTMLElement object. If I use method $, I'm sure I will get a new element object, because the code Element.extend(element) in $ ensure the method will return a new element extend by prototype. But how about createElement method? Why we can get a new extended element by the raw document.createElement method?

Comment: Thanks Geek Num 88, you gave me a lot of inspiration

Answer (score 2):

Prototype affects the prototype of `HTMLElement`, which `document.createElement` creates — hence the name. [Here’s the Prototype documentation on that.](http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions)

> ### Native extensions
>
> There is a secret behind all this.
>
> In browsers that support adding methods to prototype of native objects
>   such as `HTMLElement` *all* DOM extensions on the element are available by
>   default without ever having to call `Element.extend()`, dollar function
>   or anything!

Comment: Yew, I see it, but my question is where the prototype.js do Native extensions. Because if you haven't replace or change the createElement method, and you also haven't replace or change the HTMLElement object, you can't get a new different HTMLElement object

Comment: @user2155362: Prototype has changed the `HTMLElement` object. http://jsfiddle.net/ggUQm/

Comment: How does prototype changed the HTMLElement object, I mean which line in prototype.js

Comment: @user2155362: Do you want me to link to the source?

Answer (score 1):

`document.createElement` is just creating an `HTMLElement` which is extended by prototype.js. See http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, I think I know how protytype.js do native extentions.

```
(function(div) {

if (!Prototype.BrowserFeatures.ElementExtensions && div['__proto__']) {
    window.HTMLElement = { };
    window.HTMLElement.prototype = div['__proto__'];
    Prototype.BrowserFeatures.ElementExtensions = true;
}

div = null;})(document.createElement('div'));
```

I think this is code fragment which do native extentions.